# Can Doctrine DBAL be mixed with ORM Query Builder?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, dbal

I am trying to create a querybuilder using ORM. But I stumble upon a field on an entity with a relationship to 2 possible tables. With this structure it would be (IMHO) impossible to map it in the entity itself.

```
╔═══════╗      ╔═══════╗       ╔═══════╗
║ ValB  ║      ║ Main  ║       ║ ValC  ║
╠══╦════╣      ╠══╦════╣       ╠══╦════╣
║ *║ pk ║-- +  ║ *║ pk ║   +---║ *║ pk ║
╠══╬════╣   |  ╠══╬════╣   |   ╠══╬════╣
║  ║    ║   +--║  ║v_id║---+   ║  ║    ║
╠══╬════╣      ╠══╬════╣       ╠══╬════╣
║  ║    ║      ║  ║    ║       ║  ║    ║
╚══╩════╝      ╚══╩════╝       ╚══╩════╝
```

Is is possible to mix DBAL QueryBuilder with ORM QueryBuilder, or any other way that will still use the ORM QueryBuilder mostly on the code.

PS. I did not design the db and im just optimizing it. sorry for this :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it doesn't make sense, because later ORM have to map results to objects. You can't map both `ValB` and `ValC` to the same property in `Main`

To do it correctly, there should be separate fields in `Main` table for `ValB` and `ValC` relations. Even if they have the same value. Like this

```
╔═══════╗      ╔════════╗       ╔═══════╗
║ ValB  ║      ║ Main   ║       ║ ValC  ║
╠══╦════╣      ╠══╦═════╣       ╠══╦════╣
║ *║ pk ║-- +  ║ *║ pk  ║   +---║ *║ pk ║
╠══╬════╣   |  ╠══╬═════╣   |   ╠══╬════╣
║  ║    ║   +--║  ║vB_id║   |   ║  ║    ║
╠══╬════╣      ╠══╬═════╣   |   ╠══╬════╣
║  ║    ║      ║  ║vC_id║---+   ║  ║    ║
╚══╩════╝      ╚══╩═════╝       ╚══╩════╝
```

You could copy `v_id` column and then make proper mapping in Doctrine.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that solution, but is there a way for this not resorting into creating another table? because we are in production and its very tedious and dangerous to migrate into this structure..

Comment: I understan your problem. But no. You probably will have to stay with DBAL only here.

Comment: thank you ur answer enlightened me. I was just thinking that maybe there is a way to dynamically map the entity. But I think there's no way. Thanks! :)

Comment: Wait a second. Maybe you could try with this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder I've never tried it, but it looks nice.

Comment: Looks like this is the one I'm looking for :) havent heard of it yet but sure looks like my solution :) thanks!! ill try this one out. Btw, you should add it to your answer..